# Durbin Watson Statistic Significant but Autocorrelation Low

Tags: durbin-watson-test

I used the `durbinWatsonTest` command to test a regression for autocorrelation of error terms in R and got the following output:

`lag Autocorrelation D-W Statistic p-value`

`1      0.03016262      1.937592       0`

`Alternative hypothesis: rho != 0`

I'm wondering how can I interpret this? The p-value is obviously very low, but the discovered autocorrelation is only 0.03 (which is a very weak correlation). So is autocorrelation a problem in this regression? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How large is your sample size?

Comment: My sample size is 2,677

Comment: I think we have an example of the difference between a statistically significant and a practically significant result.   Additionally, the asymptotic distribution of the first-degree autocorrelation coefficient at that sample size has a standard deviation of 0.019, so on the edge of significance using that approach.  I wouldn't worry about the autocorrelation coefficient in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes loads of sense! Just out of curiosity (and for the future) from what level of autocorrelation should I begin to worry?

Answer (score 2):

I asked a statistics professor at my workplace about this when I observed a similar result, he said this `durbinWatsonTest` is not informative because there is no way to specify what you are testing, for autocorrelation. Instead, better to discard the test visually evaluate the relationship between standardised residuals and different variables which could introduce auocorrelation (especially space/time factors):

```
sresid<- (model1$residuals-mean(model1$residuals)/sd(model1$residuals))

plot(sresid~Dataset$suspectfactor1)
#Repeat for different factors
#Check for systematic trends or clustering
```

Comment: Hi Charlotte. While writing scripts in your post, you can use the code fences ` ``` ` for formatting the scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on code fences!

Comment: Thanks that's very informative!